# No module named "yaml"

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS on Ubuntu 11.10 using the complete desktop install from ros.org.  However, when I try to run roscore, I get the following error:

```
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/roscore", line 34, in <module>
    from ros import roslaunch
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/ros/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    return __import__(name)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import roslaunch.param_dump
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/param_dump.py", line 43, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml`
```

I found someone with the same problem here: http://answers.ros.org/question/12862/nao-error-no-module-named-yaml

I also tried to get the yaml package using, "sudo apt-get install build-essential python-yaml cmake subversion wget python-setuptools mercurial git-core", but terminal then says that python-yaml is already updated.  How can I get this yaml module working properly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30088/no-module-named-%22yaml%22/) by [Turcuivie](https://answers.ros.org/users/2024/turcuivie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-20**:
Can you just do `python -c 'import yaml; print "success"'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you do not have the `python-yaml` Ubuntu package.

It should be installed, as it is a core system dependency for ROS.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-06**:
sudo apt-get install python-yaml doesnt work.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-10-07**:
It comes with Ubuntu.